# handling modal wxDialog from PyQt application

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt, wxpython, pyqt4

So I am using PyQt to create an application with GUI (QtGui)
I have other GUIs that are created with wxPython and I want to link between them and my current application.

The problem is: I have a `wxDialog` that I want to show by clicking on `PyQt.Gui` button (There is no problem in that) and I want `wxDialog` to behave like a `QDialog` (Modal Dialog):

I want it to block its parent window until it finishes (click on OK for example)
But, all `PyQt` GUIS are children to `PyQt.QtGui.QApplication` and all `wxPython` GUIS are children to `wx.App`. So, it's like I'm running two different apps.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: It is not appropriate to mix libraries that serve the same thing, that sounds and smells like bad design. in the case of a GUI the event loops of each one will be blocked between them

Comment: @eyllanesc " in the case of a GUI the event loops of each one will be blocked between them"

I didn't get this ... could you please explain more ?

Comment: Every GUI is executed within a while loop call event loop, in that loop the GUI verifies the entries like the keyboard, the mouse, etc, and repaints the GUI, etc. in the case of PyQt you do it are QApplication.exec_ (), and in the case of WxPython it is wx.App.MainLoop (), so at some point execute one or the other, and if a while loop is executed it will block to the other, so the window of the part of the blocked GUI will not work.